# Passing the total row count to Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatable

I've got a datatables implementation that does an ajax request tho `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. I run my query to get all records when the page loads. However, the first ajax call will do this again without limit. I was wondering if it is possible to pass the total row count in the initial ajax request. This is my datatables code:

```
var myTable = $('.datatable').DataTable({
    "serverSide": true,
    "processing": true,
    "paging": true,
    "searching": { "regex": true },
    "lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"] ],
    "pageLength": 10,
    "ajax": {
        "type": "POST",
        "url": "<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>",
        "dataType": "json",
        "contentType": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        "data": function (data) {
            // Grab form values containing user options
            var form = {};
            $.each($("form").serializeArray(), function (i, field) {
                form[field.name] = field.value || "";
            });
            // Add options used by Datatables
            var info = { "start": 0, "length": 10, "draw": 1 };
            $.extend(form, info);
            return JSON.stringify(form);
        },
        "complete": function(response) {
            console.log(response);
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: with this `"url": "<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` you are likely to not get a reasonable response. Should be a seperate php.

Comment: @Jeff I check if the request is ajax and return the appropriate value accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution to my issue which in terms seemed to be multiple issues.

1. I had the wrong value for `recordsTotal` thinking it was supposed to be the amount of rows I wanted to retrieve in my ajax call.
2. `"contentType": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` seemed to break my ajax request.
3. I now pass the total number of rows using:

   "data": {
       "totalRows": "",
   },
4. I now set `$totalData` initially using a count on my query results and then overwriting it using `$_REQUEST`.